# RubyMine is not installing gems to the right directory

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, rubymine-7

I have encountered a problem where I create a ruby-on-rails application using RubyMine v7.0 and when I go to run, I get prompted with

```
C:/ruby-2.0.0-p643-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find json-1.8.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

and when I run

```
gem install 'json'
```

it succeeds but gives the same error even when I run the app again, even after running `'bundle install'`.

when I use `bundle show 'json'` it shows the gem location to be

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2
```

which is different from the location RubyMine is looking in

```
C:/ruby-2.0.0-p643-x64-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems
```

How do I change the directory that gems are installed to to the correct one stated above? any suggestions are much appreciated :)

side note: I'm running on **Windows 8**

Comment: Fellow Windows user, bummed to hear you're having this issue! What do you get when you execute `bundle show json` at the command line?

Comment: `D:\Programming\RUBY\RubyMine\Test_app_4>bundle show json`  

`DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle`  

`C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2`

Comment: ^on a side note, how do you add linebreaks to a comment? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to prequalify this answer, but I can't speak to how RubyMine sets up gems and the gem environment. That said, you can control where gems are installed by manipulating the `GEM_HOME` environment variable.

On Windows, `set` creates a user variable.

`> set GEM_HOME=c:\your_target_folder`

With `GEM_HOME` assigned, `gem install xyz` will install the gem to the directory you specified.

`> gem install xyz`

[image: gem_home_example]

Comment: I haven't tried implementing this yet as I tried creating a rails app with the ruby version from the directory the gems were installing to and it seems to work now... but I will make this the accepted answer as I am confident it answers my question!